# If $0 \in P$ and $\sup\{x \in [0,1] : [0,x] \subseteq P\} = 1$, then $[0,1] \subseteq P$? (What if adding 3rd assumption?)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, supremum-and-infimum

> Let $P \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. If $0 \in P$ and $\sup\{x \in [0,1] : [0,x] \subseteq P\} = 1$, then $[0,1] \subseteq P$.

Is the above claim true or false? How to prove or disprove it?

**Edit1:** Thanks for the quick disproof/counterexample! In fact this question originated from reading a proof that a closed and bounded interval in $\mathbb{R}$ is compact. If adding 3rd assumption:

> $\sup\{x \in [0,1] : [0,x] \subseteq P\} \in \{x \in [0,1] : [0,x] \subseteq P\}$

can this stricter claim be proven to be true?

Answer (score 2):

This is false : for $P=[0,1)$, you have that $\sup\{x\in[0,1];[0,x]\subset P\}=\sup[0,1)=1.$ Thus, $1\in[0,1]$ and $1\notin P$.

Comment: But you have defined $P$ as $[0,1]$ which contains 1, so 1 $\in P$.

Comment: No, here $P=[0,1[$ not $[0,1]$.

Comment: Oh, sorry, what does [0,1[ mean?  Is it the same as [0,1)?

Comment: It stands for $[0,1[=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\,;\,0\leq x<1\}$.

Comment: Oh sorry it was a french notation, I am here to improve my mathematical english then i'll correct that immediatly !

Comment: @Baloown: This question originated from reading a proof that a closed and bounded interval in $\mathbb{R}$ is compact. If adding the 3rd assumption: " $\sup\{x \in [0,1] : [0,x] \subseteq P\} \in \{x \in [0,1] : [0,x] \subseteq P\}$ " will this claim be true?

Comment: @Tien-ChengHuang : Yes, but here you are assuming something which is really strong : you will have that your $\sup$ is a $\max$, and if you ask this $\max$ to equals $1$ the answer is obvious.

Comment: @Tien-ChengHuang I think you are trying to prove that $[0,1]$ is compact (first part of the proof that compacts in $\mathbb{R}$ are bounded closed sets). You can try to show Borel-Lebesgue property, considerating an open cover $(U_i)_{i\in I}$ and working on the equivalence relation $x\sim y\iff \exists (U_j)_{j\in I}$ a finite cover of $[x,y]$. All you have to do is to prove that $0\sim 1$.

Answer (score 0):

(Answering the second, post-edit question).

Let $P \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Assume

1. $0 \in P$
2. $\sup\{x \in [0,1] : [0,x] \subseteq P\} = 1$.
3. $\sup\{x \in [0,1] : [0,x] \subseteq P\} \in \{x \in [0,1] : [0,x] \subseteq P\}$.

Assumption 2 substitutes into Assumption 3 to say that
$1 \in \{x \in [0,1] : [0,x] \subseteq P\}$ which implies
$1 \in [0,1]$ and  $[0,1] \subseteq P.$